# How can I prove $1^{n+2} + 2^{n+2} + 3^{n+2} + 4^{n+2}$ is divisible by $10$ for any odd $n$?

Tags: induction, divisibility

Assuming this is true:

$1^n+2^n+3^n+4^n$ divisible by $10$ for any odd $n$ ($n$ is natural)

How can I prove that for $n+2$:

$1^{n+2} + 2^{n+2} + 3^{n+2} + 4^{n+2}$

Is divisible by 10 as well ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: Show that the number is even (this is easy), and show that it is divisible by five (a bit harder, but not much - depending on your background).

Comment: $n$ odd, then $n+1$ even, then $n+2$ is odd, isn't it?

Comment: Let $S_n=1^{2n-1}+2^{2n-1}+3^{2n-1}+4^{2n-1}$. Then $2\mid \left(2^{2n-1}+4^{2n-1}\right)$ because both are even. Also $2\mid \left(1^{2n-1}+3^{2n-1}\right)$ because it is the sum of two odd numbers. Now $5\mid \left(1^{2n-1}+4^{2n-1}\right)$ because the exponents are odd. For same reason, $5\mid \left(2^{2n-1}+3^{2n-1}\right)$. Can we say now that $10\mid S_n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Induction:**
Consider the difference, $$\left(1 + 2^{n+2} + 3^{n+2} + 4^{n+2}\right)-\left(1+2^n+3^n+4^n\right).$$ Is it divisible by $10$?

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use congruences: First note that if $k$ is odd, then
$$
4^k\equiv 4\ (\text{mod}\,10).
$$
Now, if $n$ is odd, then $n+2$ is odd, so
$$
1^{n+2}+2^{n+2}+3^{n+2}+4^{n+2}\equiv
1+2^{n+2}+3^{n+2}+4=5+2^{n+2}+3^{n+2}\ (\text{mod}\,10).
$$
It suffices to prove that $5\mid 2^{n+2}+3^{n+2}$. Indeed, since $n+2$ is odd we get
$$
2^{n+2}+3^{n+2}\equiv 2^{n+2}+(-2)^{n+2}=
2^{n+2}-2^{n+2}=0\ (\text{mod}\,5).
$$
Therefore 
$$
5\mid 1^{n+2}+2^{n+2}+3^{n+2}+4^{n+2}.
$$
Since clearly 
$$
2\mid 1^{n+2}+2^{n+2}+3^{n+2}+4^{n+2}
$$
the assertion follows.